# weblogic & websphere DataSource configuration

Tags: java, websphere, weblogic, datasource, jndi

My application has to deploy and run on WebLogic and WebSphere. In CDI bean I use @Resource annotation to inject DataSource.

```
@Resource(name = "dataSources/example", mappedName = "dataSources/example")
DataSource dataSource;
```

On weblogic works properly, but on WebSphere doesn't.

> ResourceInjec E CWOWB0102E: A JCDI error has occurred: Unable to obtain an instance for dataSources/example: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/dataSources not found in context "java:".

Is there any easy configuration possibility which works in this two cases?
Thanks

Comment: It might not be a code issue. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.messages.doc%2Fcom.ibm.ws.webbeans.resources.jcdi.html tells to review the FFDC. From exception text it looks like datasource configuration issue. I have personally used @Resource injection with WebSphere and it works perfectly.

Comment: In WebSphere console the test connection is successful and its JNDI name is correct. Which version of WebSphere do you use?

Comment: I have used it on WAS 6, 6.1 and 7.0.